# Custom Class Used in A List/HashSet

Tags: java, list, equals, hashcode, hashset

I have a custom class that looks like below:

```
public class customClass(){
    private int keyCode;
    private boolean up;
    private String toTrigger;

    public String getTrigger();
    public boolean up();
    public int keyCode();
}
```

Whats the best way for performance to have a list of unique values?

I was thinking of a HashSet but how would i make sure its only unique instances of my customClass?

What do i need to override? Equals and HashCode? will that make sure that my Hash Set of CustomClass only have unique instances?

Thanks

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27609/1068167

Comment: Basically, yes: Overriding `equals` and `hashCode` is enough, but make sure to override them correctly, which is not easy. (see link from *span* above)

Comment: Ahh thanks :) So in a hash set what does the hash set use to determine if its equal? Hash code or equals?

Comment: question: you need the instance unique or the value of instance unique? you mentioned both in your question. e.g. `Dummy d1 =new Dummy("a"); and Dummy d2= new Dummy("a");` they could be equal, but they are different instances. Could d1 and d2 stay in your list/set?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overriding equals and hashCode in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a.equals(b) is true then there hashcode() **must** also be same.

- Override both .equals() and .hashCode() in your custom class.

  Use the same fields of your custom class to calculate hashCode which you used to check equality in .equals().
- Yes it'll make sure that there are only unique instances of your
  customClass in hash-set. So go for it.

Comment: **No**.  If two objects are equals, `hashCode()` **must** be the same.